# need to increase or decrease the width of <div> , when browser resizes, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to increase or decrease the width of `<div>`, when the browser resizes, using jquery. here is my code.

```
if ($(window).width() > 990 && $(window).width() < 1190) {
    $("#greybor").width(268)
    $("#srchclnt").width("245")
} else if ($(window).width() > 1200 && $(window).width() < 1300) {
    $("#greybor").width(400)
} else
    $(window).width() > 1350 {
        $("#greybor").width(580)
}
```

It's taking the last entered width, when I am resizing the browser, the `<div>` width doesn't decrease, it remains the last same.

I even tried by `addClass` and `removeClass` methods but still, it's the same thing.
thanks & regards.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you doing it with css media querys?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 2):

You should use css rules for this kind of operations and preferably by appending classes to your div elements. With Id's you could do something like that:

```
@media (max-width: 1189px) {
    .graybor  {
        width: 268px;
    }
    .srchclnt{
        width: 245px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1190px) {
    .graybor  {
        width: 400px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1301px) {
    .graybor  {
        width: 580px;
    }
}

<div class='graybor'>
    graybor area 
</div>
<div class='srchclnt'>
   srchclnt area 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1ofw5hv/

Comment: sorry my mistake, it worked with media queries, 
thanks Anastasios Selmanis.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle if it helps https://jsfiddle.net/m1ofw5hv/ with some changes you could use and I will correct my my answer.

Comment: If my answer covered your question you should accept it.